# Make Resharper Code Inspection exclude folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Working on a rather large project and one of the bigger project folders uses a company standard generated code layer.  This code layer triggers a lot of "issues" in Resharper, but right now refactoring the code generator simply isn't going to happen.

Is there a way to tell Resharper to skip this particular folder when its running a solution wide code inspection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the Resharper Options menu, click Settings under the Code Inspection section and select "Edit Items to Skip" and select your folder.

[image: Resharper menu]

Comment: When I run code cleanup it doesn't seem to be honoring the the skip filter. Is there a way to have it do this?